# LastWriteTime not changed despite file edited while code is running?

Tags: powershell

PowerShell toddler here.

Some people at work save files within subfolders, within subfolders, until the point they can't open them in Explorer by double-clicking etc. So I made a tool that can open these files, and it works like this.

Right click the file. There is an option to use my tool in the Send To menu (set up during the tool's installation process). The selected file shows up in a textbox like a generic Open file dialog. Then they click an Open button, and the code copies the file to a subfolder within their Documents folder, and opens it up from there.

Fine so far. The issue is that it is possible that the local copy gets edited and saved, and there is code to detect this newer version if the tool is used again to open the original file from the original location.

```
If ([System.IO.File]::Exists($FileName)) {

    [datetime]$DestinationFile = (Get-Item $OldFileName).LastWriteTime

    [datetime]$SourceFile = (Get-Item $FileName).LastWriteTime

    If ($DestinationFile -gt $SourceFile) {

        #Overwrite prompt and code here (in Japanese, so I won't include it)

    }

}
```

LastWriteTime seems flaky. If the file (local copy) is edited immediately after being opened by my tool, LastWriteTime does not appear to have changed, even after saving and closing the file, and my tool. This becomes apparent if the tool is used again later, LastWriteTime of the edited copy isn't getting picked up as different so the overwrite prompt and code don't kick off.

At the same time, if both the file and tool are closed, then the local copy is opened and edited, running my tool to open the original file again does show the prompt and the overwrite code works.

What goes on in higher level stuff is black magic to me. If the file is edited after being opened programatically, is it still "in a pipe"? (Everything must be shut down first or LastWriteTime cannot be modified?)

Comment: I suspect that the issue is outside the snippet that you showing, something as `$Filename` isn't updated or out of scope (common, issue with UI forms) or an `array` rather than a single (string) path. I recommend to do some logging here and use the PowerShell cmdlet `Test-Path` (rather than the .net `file.exists` method and also use the `-LiteralPath` parametr for `Get-Item` cmdlet. Or just prove the "black magic" with a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate you taking the time to help. Using ```-Force``` as in the answer to my post did the trick.

Comment: Good to hear, I did although vote to close the question as the actual suggested issue "**LastWriteTime not changed despite file edited while code is running?**" is not reproducible.

Comment: That's only fair. Unfortunately the code called if the condition is met is quite long, to the extent that it might distract from the actual issue.

Comment: Your answer might be useful if you try to prevent others from the same pitfall and change the question with a (to the point issue) and a [mcve] that includes something  like `try{ Copy-Item ... }` where someone might miss the fact that the file isn't copied if the file already exists.

Answer (score 1):

This smells to me like your in-memory object is simply out-of-sync with the filesystem.

If you have a FileInfo, DirectoryInfo, or FileSystemInfo object in memory by a variable and make changes to the referenced object on disk, you may need to call the `Refresh()` method to force the object in memory to update.

```
PS C:\Users\User> $File = Join-Path -Path $env:USERPROFILE -ChildPath Test.txt
PS C:\Users\User> Set-Content -Path $File -Value ''
PS C:\Users\User> $f = Get-Item -Path $File
PS C:\Users\User> Start-Sleep -Seconds 30
PS C:\Users\User> Set-Content -Path $File -Value ''
PS C:\Users\User> $f.LastWriteTime

Friday, May 12, 2023 2:58:24 PM

PS C:\Users\User> (Get-Item -Path $File).LastWriteTime

Friday, May 12, 2023 2:58:54 PM

PS C:\Users\User> $f.Refresh()
PS C:\Users\User> $f.LastWriteTime

Friday, May 12, 2023 2:58:54 PM
```

See also [the `FileSystemInfo.Refresh()` method in the .Net class documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesysteminfo.refresh?view=net-8.0).

Answer (score 0):

I've played around a bit more with the code and found if I use `-Force` where appropiate with `Copy-Item`, `Move-Item`, `Remove-Item`, then my aforementioned code that compares `LastWriteTime` between the original file and the edited file works as expected.